# Oracle SQL, avoiding errror "table is mutating" (trigger)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i need trigger which will check if updated worker can be moved to other team

```
CREATE TABLE WORKERS 
(   
    ID_WORKER NUMBER(4,0), --FK
    ID_TEAM NUMBER(2,0) --FK
);
```

My trigger looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEAM_LIMIT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ID_TEAM ON WORKERS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  V_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT Count(*) INTO V_num FROM Worker WHERE ID_TEAM=:new.ID_TEAM;
  IF V_num >= 5 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20025,' Error nr ... bleble');
  END IF;
END;
```

this generate error : "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" when row is updated. How to write this statements properly to not generate this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compound trigger, it looks like this (not tested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEAM_LIMIT
FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OF ID_TEAM ON WORKERS 
COMPOUND TRIGGER

V_num NUMBER;

TYPE Row_TableType IS TABLE OF WORKERS.ID_TEAM%TYPE;
AffectedTeams Row_TableType;    

BEFORE STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    AffectedTeams := Row_TableType(); -- init the table variable   
END BEFORE STATEMENT;
-------------------
BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    AffectedTeams.EXTEND;
    AffectedTeams(AffectedTeams.LAST) := :NEW.ID_TEAM;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
--------------------
AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN AffectedTeams.FIRST..AffectedTeams.LAST LOOP
       SELECT Count(*) INTO V_num FROM Worker WHERE ID_TEAM=AffectedTeams(i);
       IF V_num >= 5 THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20025,' Error nr ... bleble');
       END IF;        
    END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END TEAM_LIMIT;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a statement trigger. Statement triggers are only fired once for each statement executed rather than once for each row affected. Statement triggers are useful because they don't have the restriction that they can't query the table on which the trigger is declared. They don't have access to the :OLD and :NEW row values but with a little thought you can still accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEAM_LIMIT
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ID_TEAM ON WORKERS
  -- Note: no FOR EACH ROW - therefore, this is a statement trigger
DECLARE
  nMax_team_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(TEAM_COUNT)
    INTO nMax_team_count
    FROM (SELECT ID_TEAM, COUNT(*) AS TEAM_COUNT
            FROM WORKERS
            GROUP BY ID_TEAM));

  IF nMax_team_count >= 5 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20025,' Error nr ... bleble');
  END IF;
END TEAM_LIMIT;
```

Instead of looking at the team of the particular work which has been updated we find the counts of workers on each team, then extract the largest count, and if it's more than four we raise the appropriate exception.

Share and enjoy.